# Leading or trailing whitespace and pandas value_counts vs boolean selection

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with a dataframe created from a csv file downloaded from my county's Sheriff's Department.  The data is located [here](https://data.sonomacounty.ca.gov/Public-Safety/Sonoma-County-Sheriff-s-Office-Incident-Data/3rsj-iche) and can be read in using `read_csv()`.  The dataframe contains information about incidents reported to and acted upon by the Sheriff. One of the columns is the city in which the incident occurred, and I'm trying to create a table and graph showing the change in number of incidents for my area (Larkfield) over time.

When I use panda's value_counts function using "city" as an input, I get

```
In [86]: compcounts = soco['city'].value_counts()
In [96]: compcounts[0:10]
Out[96]:
SANTA ROSA              55291
WINDSOR                 31711
SONOMA                  28840
GUERNEVILLE              9309
BOYES HOT SPRINGS        8006
PETALUMA                 6103
EL VERANO                5969
GEYSERVILLE              5822
LARKFIELD                5398
FORESTVILLE              5312
dtype: int64`
```

There are 5398 reports for my area ('Larkfield'). But when I try to get a subset of the dataframe for my area, using

```
larkfieldcomps = soco[soco['city'] == "LARKFIELD"]
```

it returns only 115 values, not 5398:

```
In [94]: larkcounts = larkfieldcomps['year'].value_counts()
In [95]: larkcounts
Out[95]:
2015    114
2013      1
dtype: int64
```

I thought maybe the problem was that in some entries there was one or more spaces before or after "LARKFIELD" in the incident description, so I did a search/replace to try to strip out any spaces, but I still get only 115 values when searching by "LARKFIELD," even though I know there are many more incidents in that area.

This is my first question on Stackoverflow ... I've researched this to death but haven't come up with an answer yet. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What does `len(larkcounts)` show? you may have `NaN` values in your years which are not being counted in `value_counts`

Comment: For instance does `larkfieldcomps['year'].value_counts(dropna=False)` give you 5398 total?

Comment: Thanks Ed, I'd checked that already, and I also scanned the dataframe visibly and found rows where "LARKFIELD" was the 'city' value and the date was something other than 2015 or 2013. I'm still mystified.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't accidentally set one of the variables to something else somewhere along the line?  Without sample data it's difficult to know what is going on.

Comment: The underlying data is [link]https://data.sonomacounty.ca.gov/Public-Safety/Sonoma-County-Sheriff-s-Office-Incident-Data/3rsj-iche. Interestingly enough, that web page has its own data manipulation functions embedded in it, and the same thing happens when you use them: Ask it to "filter" using "LARKFIELD" as the city, and it gives you 121 reports; ask it to "sort" by 'city', and when you scroll down to "LARKFIELD", there are about 6000 listed. Maybe it's not me after all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can somewhat explain this after downloading the data (and reading into a dataframe with `read_csv` using default settings).  It appears that there are leading or trailing spaces in there.  Apparently `value_counts` is smart enough to ignore this when adding things up but the boolean selection is much more literal.

```
>>> soco[soco['city'] == "LARKFIELD"].city.count()
122

>>> soco['city2'] = soco.city.str.strip()

>>> soco[soco['city2'] == "LARKFIELD"].city.count()
5520
```

And when I look a little closer it seems that 5398 have 11 trailing spaces and 122 have no spaces.  So that's the difference.  (I'm not sure why you find 115 values for year instead of 122, but that's most likely due to some missing values for year, however you created it.)

But then I did this to double check the behavior of `value_counts` because I had been assuming that leading and trailing spaces would matter.

```
>>> pd.Series( [' foo','foo','foo '] ).value_counts() 
foo     1
foo     1
 foo    1
```

And, yeah, in this simple example leading and trailing blanks do indeed matter.  But they don't in your 'soco' dataframe???

So there are still some loose ends here, but hopefully this is a good start for figuring out what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks JohnE. I thought whitespaces might be the problem and had tried to strip them out, but being relatively new to Python and pandas I think I may have not done that correctly. I'll try again and see if that changes things.

Comment: @SSShupe I'm glad that helps although I am still not 100% sure what is happening here.  Another thing I noticed is that not everything in the city column is read in as a string (there are a small number of floats).  You may want to change your `read_csv` to be explicit about dtype.  Btw, I edited the title to hopefully make it more descriptive with respect to the underlying issue.